# D7100: How to adjust default settings?

Tags: nikon, camera-settings, presets

On a Nikon D7100 it's possible to reset all settings to the default values by simultaneously holding the two buttons that have green dots next to them.  This is very useful for recalling a starting point state after having changed several settings.

Is it possible to adjust what these "defaults" are?

Specifically I would prefer to set the default quality to RAW instead of normal large JPEG.

Comment: When does the quality setting return back to jpeg? Never had that problem. I set it to RAW once and never looked back.

Answer (score 4):

The *default* settings are so called because they are what the designers of the camera selected to be the standard settings for your camera. Short of writing your own firmware revision for the camera there is no way for you to alter a *default* setting and then have the camera return to that setting when you do a *default reset*.

Answer (score 1):

You have the U1 and U2 modes on the mode dial where you can set your own settings. Once you have the camera configured the way you like go into the menu and register your settings. There may be more information on page 55 of your manual.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but this is not what I need.  I am familiar with U1/U2 modes.  Switching back to, say, M mode, will also bring back the settings I last used outside of U1/U2.  I am looking to achieve precisely what I described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set the default quality to RAW instead of normal large JPEG, it is not necessary to reset all of the camera's settings to factory default. You need only press the QUAL button on the back and turn the rear control dial to cycle through the various RAW and/or JPG settings the the one you desire.

Comment: Wasn't he asking about resetting all setting to defaults, *except* the quality, which should be kept at RAW?

Comment: That's not how I read his statement: "Specifically I would prefer to set the default quality to RAW instead of normal large JPEG."

Comment: He wants to quality to be reset to RAW instead of JPEG when he presses the two green buttons.